# How to copy a mysql table to another in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Can any one guide me for how can i copy one mysql table to another table in same database using cakephp please give me example query if possible.

Comment: You should learn to use the mysql command line client. Run your query directly, you don't need to write a program to do it when MySQL comes with a program for running queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a quick and dirty one time copy, I'd just loop over the source table records and create new target records:

```
$source = $this->Source->find('all');
foreach($source as $sRec)
{
    $this->Target->create();
    $targetData = array();
    $target['Target']['field1'] = $sRec['Source']['field1'];
    $target['Target']['field2'] = $sRec['Source']['field2'];
    //etc
    $this->Target->save($targetData);
}
```

Apologies if it's buggy, I've just splurged it.

*Edited to show row selection conditional. Something along the lines of:*

```
$toCopy = array(1,32,71,72,73);
foreach($toCopy as $anId)
{
    $sRec = $this->Source->read(null,$anId);
    $this->Target->create();
    $targetData = array();
    $target['Target']['field1'] = $sRec['Source']['field1'];
    $target['Target']['field2'] = $sRec['Source']['field2'];
    //etc
    $this->Target->save($targetData);
}
```

Comment: can i copy only the rows according to supplied id

Comment: Yes. If you're happy to stay dirty and speed isn't an issue (only applies if the table is BIG) just add a conditional - see my edit.

Comment: Why isn't the $target['Target']['field1'] etc - $targetData['Target']['field1']

Answer (score 4):

```
create table new_table like your_table;
insert into new_table select * from your_table;
```

The above will keep index for new_table

```
create table new_table select * from your_table;
```

The above will not keep index.
There is nothing to do with cakephp, you just need the correct sql syntax,
plus relevant connection setting to allow php connect to mysql

Comment: If you must do it from within CakePHP, this would have to be done as $this->MyModel->query('SOME SQL');

Comment: as you told there is nothing to do with cakephp. then where do i write this query.

Comment: **1.** use a mysql client program to run above script. **2.** write a PHP script (not necessary to use cakephp framework) to run above sql.