# How to copy result of a query to another table CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to copy a query I made from one table to another, I've already seen old answers but I want to know if there is a new and better way to cakephp3.

[How to copy a mysql table to another in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860638/how-to-copy-a-mysql-table-to-another-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

If both tables has the same schema - its pretty simple (example in controller):

```
$this->loadModel('Bikes');
$this->loadModel('Bicycles');

$toCopy = $this->Bikes->find('all')->hydrate(FALSE)->toArray();

$columns = $this->Bikes->schema()->columns();
$query = $this->Bicycles->query();

array_map(function($item) use($query, $columns) {
    $query
        ->insert($columns)
        ->values($item);
}, $toCopy);

$query->execute();
```